# count number of 1's in a column based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have this dataframe

```
 Country    |    Value
 England           1
 England           1
 England           2
  USA              3
  USA              3
  USA              2
 Germany           1
 Thailand          2
```

My desired Dataframe

```
Country    |    Value      Cat 1   cat 2  cat 3
 England           1        2       1      0
  USA              3        0       1      2
 Germany           1       1        0      0
 Thailand          2       0        1      0
```

Comment: What is `cat 2`?

Comment: cat 1  is no of 1's record for same country.
cat 2 is no of 2's  record for same counrty.

Comment: Okay, so shouldn't cat 2 for USA be 1 rather than 0? shouldn't it also be 1 rather than 2 for England?

Comment: Welcome to stcak overflow. Your question isn't clear, what is the algorithm for how each column gets filled out, and what have you tried based on your own research? For example, should there be an entry in `cat 2` for `USA`?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to count the number of repetitions using a dictionary. You can iterate through the rows of a dataframe using the "iterrows" method.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# This dictionary will be used to count the number of ocurrences of a given string.
d = defaultdict(int)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    country = row['Country']
    value = row['Value']
    if value ==1:
    d[country] += 1

# We define the column with the following function
df['Cat 1'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda text: d[text])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `unstack` the inner level of `value_counts`

```py
out = (df.value_counts(['Country', 'Value'])
       .unstack().fillna(0)
       .add_prefix('Cat ')
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reset_index())
out['Value'] = df.groupby(['Country'])['Value'].first().values
```

```
print(out)

    Country  Cat 1  Cat 2  Cat 3  Value
0   England    2.0    1.0    0.0      1
1   Germany    1.0    0.0    0.0      1
2  Thailand    0.0    1.0    0.0      2
3       USA    0.0    1.0    2.0      3
```